# Resources for getting started with Lotus Notes and LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes

I recently joined a company. I need to work on Lotus Designer software, and command and Lotus Script. I really have no idea of where to start. I have to learn from scratch on my own. Can any of you please help me on the materials I need to start with (since there are billions on internet) and how to proceed. It will be of a great help.

Thank you,

Priya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following books will be helpful.

"Lotus Notes and Domino 6 Programming Bible" by Brian Benz and Rocky Oliver.

"Teach yourself LotusScript® for Notes/Domino 4.6" by Bill Kreisle, Rocky Cliver and Rocky Oliver

The first is newer, but isn't exclusively devoted to LotusScript.  The fact that it covers topics other than Lotusscript may be helpful to you if you're new to Notes.  The second is older and won't cover some of the newer object types.  It's still fine for the basics.

Bill Buchan's blog has a list of links to Lotusscript presentations he has given:
http://www.billbuchan.com/presentations/
Many can be downloaded.  Some are quite advanced; others are more basic.  If you avoid doing the things he references in "Worst Practices", you'll be off to a great start.

If you're interested in object-oriented programmingm, my own article on Object-Oriented Lotusscript is here: 
(revised link) http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-object_oriented_LotusScript/

Comment: Thank you so much...but I am not able to open your article on object-oriented lotusscript.

Comment: Hmm. try this link. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-object_oriented_LotusScript/.  I've no idea why the other isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I started with the built-in templates.  Get to know how they work first, then open up Designer and look at all the design elements, the views, forms, etc.  Read the formulas and LotusScript thoroughly and learn what they are doing.  You'll learn good practices at the same time since the templates are thoughtfully designed.

Do the same for the databases you will be supporting at your company.

Understand the difference between an RDBMS and a document database.  Notes is the latter and that can be confusing coming from SQL or other relational databases.

If you need any basics on LotusScript, it is closely related to VB script and you might find more examples for VB.  once you know the basics, though, I'd stick to the Notes docs for learning about what each function does.

I'd also read the Lotus Notes questions and answers on StackOverflow.  Not all apply but look through for interesting ones. There are only about 400 right now.

Comment: The Lotus Designer help is also a great resource.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote any answers or comments you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [The Learning Continuum Company](http://www.tlcc.com/).  They have a variety of courseware for Notes and Domino, and they always have a couple of free and demo courses in their offerings.

Comment: Hmmm... I lost reputation points for posting this.  Relatively new to StackExchange, and I don't get why.  I'm not connected with the vendor, and I pointed out that they have free introductory courseware, which seems to me to be a pretty good way to address the questioner's request for materials that would help him get started.

Comment: rhs, I'm guessing someone put a "down" vote on your response - probably because they weren't thinking about the fact that the question actually asked for vendor information. Ah well, I gave you an up vote....